# xml function not working

Tags: php, xml, oop

```
<?php
    class prices{

        public $xml;
        public $data;
        public $xmlCount;
        public $type_id;

        function loadXml(){
            /*
             * Checks for xml file errors
             */

            libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
            $xml = simplexml_load_file('./lib/xml/items.xml');
            if (!$xml){
                echo "Failed Loading XML\n";
                foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error){
                    echo "\t", $error->message;
                }
            }

            $xmlCount = count($xml->row);

            /*
             * Should belong in xmlToSql, but here to test, this code works within this function
             */
            echo '<pre>';
            echo count($xml->row);
            echo $xml->row->{'type_id'};

            /*
             * Code to test xml output
             * echo "<br />";
             * print_r($xml);
             * echo "<br />";
              *print_r($xml);
             */
        }

        function xmlToSql(){

            /*
             * add sql code later, testing that xml is working correctly
             */

            $this->loadXml();

            /*
             * This does not work in this function
             * $type_id = $xml->row->{'type_id'};
             */
            /*
             * Should Display data
             */
            echo $xml->row->{'type_id'};
            }
      }
?>
```

Hello, I am new to php oop. I am currently in early stage of this project.

Currenlty stuck on this part, watched a few tutorials on xml and have had limited sucess.

When I call the function loadXml in xmlToSql function within the same class I cannot use the xml data. I have added notes to my code above and I hope it shows what I am trying to achive, I want to use this ...

```
echo $xml->row->{'type_id'};
```

in the function xmlToSql.

I assume im making a silly mistake.

I would appreciate any help

Comment: What does your XML file look like?  Probably you need to access an array element like `echo $xml->row[0]->{'type_id'};`

Comment: the code works in loadXml() where the xml file is loaded. xml looks like this `<result>
    <row>
        <type_id>34</type_id>
    </row>
</result>`

Comment: when I add this `echo $xml->row[0]->{'type_id'};`  to `xmlToSql()` i get this error `Trying to get property of non-object`. Looks like the `$xml` varable isnt being assigned the xml data.

Comment: It's a variable scoping issue. See answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to have missed something obvious yesterday...

When you call `$this->loadXml()`, the variable `$xml` is not stored into the object property `$this->xml`, and goes out of scope when you try to access `$xml->row`.

Store it into `$this->xml` and then access it accordingly inside `$this->xmlToSql()`:

```
function loadXml(){ 
        /*
         * Checks for xml file errors
         */
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

        // Store in $this->xml
        $this->xml = simplexml_load_file('./lib/xml/items.xml');
        if (!$this->xml){
            echo "Failed Loading XML\n";
            foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error){
                echo "\t", $error->message;
            }
        }
        // etc....
 }

function xmlToSql(){

        /*
         * add sql code later, testing that xml is working correctly
         */

        $this->loadXml();
        /*
         * Access via `$this->xml`
         */
        echo $this->xml->row->{'type_id'};\
        // or $this->xml->row[0]->{'type_id'} if necessary
        }
  }
```